# What are Capistrano binstubs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm new to Rails and wish to deploy my app to `Ubuntu 14` using `Capistrano`. Can someone explain to me what are `binstubs` and whether they are required for deploying my rails app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A binstub is an executable script that wraps a Ruby command to ensure that a specific version of that command is used.

The reason binstubs are sometimes necessary is because a given named Ruby command can refer to many different things, and so you can't be 100% sure of what the name refers to. In deployment, predictability is very important: you want to be 100% sure of what code you are running, especially in production.

For example, consider the command named `rails`. You might have multiple versions of Rails installed. Indeed, every time you upgrade to the latest patch release for security fixes, that is another new version you're installing. On top of that, you might have multiple versions of Ruby installed, too.

So when you run the command `rails`, which version of Ruby is used? Which version of Rails?

A binstub makes this decision explicit. The idea is that you create a special script and place it in the `bin` directory of your project, say `bin/rails`. This script uses Bundler to guarantee the right version of Rails is used. When you run `bin/rails`, you get that guarantee. (When you generate a new Rails project, Rails in fact creates this and other binstubs for you.)

Anyway, technically you do not need these binstubs so long as you use `bundle exec rails`. The `bundle exec` wrapper essentially does the same thing that a binstub would do.

If you use the `capistrano/rails` gem in combination with the `capistrano/bundler` gem (make sure both are in your Capfile), then Capistrano will always use `bundle exec` and you won't have to worry about creating your own binstubs.